# Calling a widget via clased based function without filling all the parameters

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to solve wherein I wanna call a function that is inside a class here is the sample code of it.

reusable_components.dart

```
class FormFields {
  static textFormFieldWidget(
      TextEditingController controller,
      String hintText,
      String helpText,
      IconData prefixIcon,
      IconData suffixIcon,
      bool isPassword,
      bool enabled,
      bool readOnly,
      Color borderColor) {
    return TextFormField(
        controller: controller,
        readOnly: readOnly == null ? false : true,
        obscureText: isPassword == null ? false : true,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.greenAccent,
              width: 1.0,
            ),
          ),
          enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.greenAccent,
              width: 1.0,
            ),
          ),
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: null == borderColor ? Colors.teal : borderColor,
              width: 1.0,
            ),
          ),
          hintText: null == hintText ? '' : hintText,
          helperText: null == helpText ? '' : helpText,
          prefixIcon: null == prefixIcon ? null : Icon(prefixIcon),
          suffix: null == suffixIcon ? null : Icon(suffixIcon),
          enabled: null == enabled ? true : false,
        ));
  }
}
```

as you can see in the parameter there's a lot, however I am having a trouble wherein it says `9 positional arguments found but only 3 found` I just wanna access 3 of the parameter...

Whenever I try to call it like this

login_page.dart - is a statefulwidget

```
final TextEditingController _userEmail =  TextEditingController();
FormFields.textFormFieldWidget(controller: _userEmail, hintText: "Hello", helpText: "Help me");
```

I do get this error message saying `The named parameter 'controller' isn't defined. Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'controller'`

I am expecting that it would accept the parameters since I did not require it.

I am new to the flutter/dart so I would appreciate your answers with a simple to understand solution. Thank you!

Comment: Don't you get a bunch of warnings for your code, testing all those variables for null that you defined as non-null? First step is *always* to listen to your compiler/linter and make sure your program works 100% according to them. Listening to them, they will automatically lead you to your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use named parameters, you need to wrap the parameter list in curly braces in the function definition:

```dart
  static textFormFieldWidget({ // <-- add curly brace here
      TextEditingController controller,
      String hintText,
      String helpText,
      IconData prefixIcon,
      IconData suffixIcon,
      bool isPassword,
      bool enabled,
      bool readOnly,
      Color borderColor }) // <-- and here
```

As you have it, the parameters are positional only, and cannot be specified by name.
Another issue you may have with the way you are trying to use this function is that all of the parameter are non-nullable and don't have default values, so you will have to provide non-null values for all of them. You can make a type nullable by appending a question mark to it, and/or you can provide default values in the parameter list:

```dart
  static textFormFieldWidget({ 
      TextEditingController controller,
      String hintText,
      String helpText = 'HELP ME!', // <-- this has a default value, so doesn't have to be provided 
      IconData? prefixIcon, // <-- this type is now nullable, so doesn't have to be provided
      IconData suffixIcon,
      bool isPassword,
      bool enabled,
      bool readOnly,
      Color borderColor })
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for explaining it now I know more about the null-able, when I added the ``?`` in the IconData, the ``prefixIcon`` is now available in the parameter therefore it is now recognized inside the parameter, Thank you!